# How to access screen capture function of DDMS by IP

Tags: android, screen, screenshot, adb, ddms

Looking for a program, or, if it doesn't exist, a way to capture the screen of an Android-based device (proprietary touch-remotes) by entering the IP address of the device.

Anyone know of something that could do this for me or, if not, what I might need to do to package up something that could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Actually, I ended up writing a simple C++ program that asks for an IP address in a console window, does command "adb connect " with the input IP address, thus establishing a connection via ADB to a device at a specified IP address, and then the C++ program starts up "Droid@Screen" software. Since the ADB is already started, the program will simply display whatever is coming in from the ADB! I have a feeling other 3rd party programs would work too.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the "screen capture" capability is built into Android itself - DDMS simply invokes it.

It would be fairly straightforward to:

a) write an Android service, that
 b) listens on a port, and
 c) does its own screen capture when invoked.

Here's an example for programmatically doing a screen capture:

- [Get Webview content into bitmap](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5bab2668cd5ab44f/efd2e7cfd14e4b16?lnk=gst&q=yahoo#efd2e7cfd14e4b16)
- [Android Screenshots and Screen Capture](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Is there another way you know of that doesn't involve service changes?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [Wifi ADB](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-adb/com.ttxapps.wifiadb) to setup an ADB connection over Wifi. It should then be possible to get the screen shot using the device using DDMS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm trying to accomplish it without wifi. The device will have a definite IP address that we can connect to from a computer.