# the "screen capture" capability is built into Android itself?

Tags: android

all

(1) Try to capture google map v2 screen but same result with this post.
[Capture screen shot of GoogleMap Android API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773658/capture-screen-shot-of-googlemap-android-api-v2)

(2) From 
[How to access screen capture function of DDMS by IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814476/how-to-access-screen-capture-function-of-ddms-by-ip)
I saw **"Actually, the "screen capture" capability is built into Android itself - DDMS simply invokes"**.

But how to invoke the "screen capture capability built into Android itself" by java language not via DDMS ? (Because I can capture the google map v2 screen from DDMS and the result is OK.)

Thanks.